# Increase size of Wubi install

Tags: installation, wubi

I want to increase the disk space for Ubuntu that I installed using wubi. I followed the instructions in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeWubiDisk. Unfortunately, these commands could not be executed :

```
du -h --apparent-size /media/win/ubuntu/disks/root.disk
fsck -f /media/win/ubuntu/disks/root.disk
```

The error message tells me:

```
cannot access `/media/win/ubuntu/disks/root.disk': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that sort of resize you need to boot a live CD/USB and mount the `NTFS` partition containing the `root.disk`. Then use the full path to the `root.disk` in all the instructions.

In summary. You can't do that from a Wubi install and you have to know where the `root.disk` is.

e.g. you installed on `C:\` and that happens to be `/dev/sda3`, then you would first mount `/dev/sda3`:

```
sudo mkdir /media/win
sudo mount /dev/sda3 /media/win
```

And then you can address the `root.disk` as: `/media/win/ubuntu/disks/root.disk`

If instead you want to do a resize while running the Wubi install, this alternate method will create a new duplicate `root.disk`: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeandDuplicateWubiDisk. It takes more space (and takes more time) but you don't need to run it from a live CD.

Comment: It seems that the NTFS partition is not available
`ubuntu@ubuntu:/media$ df -h 
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on 
/cow           1008M  151M  806M  16% / 
udev            999M  4.0K  999M   1% /dev 
tmpfs           403M  812K  402M   1% /run 
/dev/sdb1       3.8G  1.7G  2.1G  46% /cdrom 
/dev/loop0      667M  667M     0 100% /rofs
tmpfs          1007M  8.0K 1007M   1% /tmp 
none            5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock 
none           1007M   76K 1007M   1% /run/shm
/dev/sda1       228M   28M  188M  13% /media/win`

Comment: The `root.disk` cannot on `/dev/sda1` as that partition is only 228M in size.

Comment: I found it using `sudo blkid` command. It is sda3. Thanks